# How to send the array of string and json array in android ion library?

Tags: android, arrays, json, android-ion

I am facing the issue in passing the JSON array in ion library. How can I send the send the two JSON arrays and the JSON objects in the ion library.

In the below code how can I pass the json array into the ion library.

```
JsonObject jsonObject = new JsonObject();
JsonArray keywordTags = new JsonArray();
for (String tagsKeyWord:tags) {
    JsonPrimitive jsonPrimitive = new JsonPrimitive(tagsKeyWord);
    keywordTags.add(jsonPrimitive);
}

jsonObject.add("tags",keywordTags);

Ion.with(this)
    .load("http://database/api/scamer-database")
    .setHeader("Authorization", authorization)
    .setTimeout(60 * 60 * 1000);

    .setMultipartParameter("city_subur",city)
    .setMultipartParameter("state",state)
    .setMultipartParameter("postalCode",postalCode)
    .setMultipartParameter("tags", jsonObject.toString() )
    .setMultipartParameter("tactics",tactic)
    .withResponse()
    .setCallback(new FutureCallback<Response<JsonObject>>() {
        @Override
        public void onCompleted(Exception e, Response<JsonObject> result) {
        }
    });
```

The output is like

```
{
  "city_subur": "Homenickside",
  "state": "Bartellside",
  "postalCode": "46228-0535",
    "tags": [
    "tag name 1",
    "tag name 2",
    "Apply Online"
  ]
  "tactic": [
    "Called me",
    "Asked My Mobile #",
    "Asked my account number"
  ]
}
```

How can I add the tags fields in an ion library? Please help me how to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

Set the `JsonObject` using `.setJsonObjectBody(YOUR_JSON)`.

Example:

```
Ion.with(this)
   .load("http://database/api/scamer-database")
   .setJsonObjectBody(YOUR_JSON)
   ....
```

Extra Bonus: Use [this library](https://github.com/afollestad/ason) to make playing JSONs more simple.

Comment: is it possible to send the json array in ion library

Comment: @PrabhaKaran I'm not entirely sure. As per my knowledge you can pass `JsonArray` in the `.setJsonObjectBody(YOUR_JSON_ARRAY)` method